# Get List of Item that contains of another list

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, lambda, linq-to-entities

Please consider this string list:

```
Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, El Salvador,
Equatorial, Guinea, Eritrea, Estonia
Ethiopia, Panama, Papua, Paraguay
Peru, Togo, Trinidad & Tobago, Tunisia, Turkey
```

and I have another list:

```
tan, ia, Tu
```

I want all countries that contains `tan` or `ia` or `Tu`. How I can do this without `foreach` loop?

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: I can do this with foreach on second list and union result. But I want to know if it possible with 1 query?

Comment: Try *Linq* (which perform the loop for you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like that;

```
var listA = new List<string> {"Afghanistan", "England"};
var listB = new List<string> {"afg"};
listA = listA.Where(x => listB.Any(k => x.IndexOf(k, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)).ToList();
```

Also, I have ignored the case sensitive. If you want to perform case sensitive use 
`x.IndexOf(k, StringComparison.Ordinal)` instead of `x.IndexOf(k, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: Please, be careful with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` option: it may appear that Por**tu**gal should not be selected (the question states that we should look for `Tu`, not for `tu`)

Comment: Thank you for feedback, but I couldn't see any problem with Por*tugal* which is contains "tu".

Comment: You've put the comment on case sensitive/insensitive, so, please, have +1 from me. The problem I've mentioned is the question states "I want all countries that contains `tan, ia, Tu`...". Now, please, notice `Tu` 
which (in my understanding) can well mean *case sensitive* search: **Tu**rkey, **Tu**valu, but not Por**tu**gal

Comment: It could be better to decide which OP want to use case sensitive or not. If he want to perform case sensitive he can use Contains or x.IndexOf(k, StringComparison.Ordinal). The answers are pretty clear :)

Answer (score 2):

Try *Linq* which will perform the loop for you:

```
  List<string> source = new List<string>() {
    "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria",
  };

  string[] filters = new[] {"tan", "ia", "Tu"};

  List<string> result = source
    .Where(country => filters.Any(filter => country.Contains(filter)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple Where statement with checking all the filters inside as so:

```
var countries = new List<string>
    {
        "Afghanistan",
        "Albania",
        "Algeria",
        "El Salvador",
        "Equatorial",
        "Guinea",
        "Eritrea",
        "Estonia",
        "Ethiopia",
        "Panama",
        "Papua",
        "Paraguay",
        "Peru",
        "Togo",
        "Trinidad & Tobago",
        "Tunisia",
        "Turkey"
    };
    var filters = new List<string> {"tan", "ia", "Tu"};
    var result = countries.Where(country => filters.Any(filter => country.Contains(filter)));
    foreach (var resultItem in result)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(resultItem);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Also check it in this fiddle:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/PdZvp4